# Switching spring application context or Impl java classes using maven profiles

Tags: spring, maven, maven-3

I know the question I'm asking must be answered somewhere but I cant find an example on the net with some guidelines.

I wish to swap out the **Spring 3.0** bean definition at build and runtime for a common codebase. I'm also using Maven profiles to build different versions of the same code.

Currently my bean def is

```
<bean id="somebean" class="com.x.SomeImpl" >
```

I will need to replace and deploy it at some times as

```
<bean id="somebean" class="com.x.SomeOtherImpl" >
```

Now the approaches I'm thinking of are

1) Use Maven profiles to switch out the complete applicationContext.xml to some other applicationContextB.xml based on the Maven profile.

2) Use Maven profiles to somehow? replace only the bean id definition for "somebean"

My questions are:

a) How can Option 2 be achieved?

b) These approaches still compile and package both SomeImpl and SomeOtherImpl during build. How can I pick only one and not the other for compliation and packaging into EAR?

I know Spring 3.1 has env profiles for the beans, but presently that's not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using the maven resources and [filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) feature available.  You could have placeholders in your context file and a property file per profile holding values.  In each profile, you could use a different property file and appropriately have your context file filtered.

Comment: Right - so this explains part (a). any idea how I can pick and choose the java files to include/exclude in the EAR

Comment: Be careful that you don't end up with unpredictable builds, especially in multi-module projects, if you can have the same binary artefact in your local repo with different baked-in config files depending on which profile you build with. Easiest way to avoid this is to tag the artefact differently in each profile.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [Maven Build Helper Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) add-source.

You can combine profiles and Build Helper Plugin (add-source goal) to add the required classes in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can import multiple config files to your config like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">    
    <import resource="applicationContextA.xml"/>
    <import resource="applicationContextB"/>
</beans>
```

For switching you can use Spring profiles.